# Multiple plots on same graph for different parameter?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I would like to be able to `Plot` a function (with an implicit `Integrate` command) with various values for a certain parameter (`phi` in the code below for values `0.01` and `0.02`) all on the same `Plot` to compare.Below is my code:

```
e = 1.60217657*10^-19;
n = 10^-9/e;
R = 1.5;
sigma = 50*10^-6;
p = (R*phi^3)/(24 sigma);
g = D[Exp[-((curlEprime)^2/2)], curlEprime];

G = p^(-(1/3)) (Exp[-((curlE - p)^2/2)] - Exp[-((curlE - 4 p)^2/2)]) +
Integrate[1/(curlE - curlEprime)^(1/3) g, {curlEprime, curlE - p, curlE}];

de = (2 e^2 n)/(3^(1/3) Sqrt[2 Pi] R^(2/3) sigma^(4/3)) G

Plot[de, {curlE, -10, 10}] /. phi -> {0.01, 0.02}
```

Comment: Define all your variable depending on `phi` as `var[phi_]:=`. Then `Plot[de[phi],...]` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. tried it but no luck :/

Comment: You need `p[phi_]`, `g[curlEPrime_]`, `G[phi_, curlE_, curlEprime_]` and `de[phi_, curlE_, curlEprime_]`. I haven't looked in the details so I might be wrong about `curlEprime` but here is the idea. Then you will be able to plot `Plot[de[#,..] /@ {0.01, 0.02},...]`.

Answer (score 3):

Below you'll find a slightly changed version of your code (note the new definition of g - saves some space). Basically, as Öskå wrote in his comments above, you need to define functions of `phi`, `curlEprime` and `curlE`. Also, it seems that the integral could not be derived in a symbolic way.

Furthermore, you **should not** name your variable with capital letters (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1356)), hence the small changes bellow:

```
e = 1.60217657*10^-19;
n = 10^-9/e;
r = 1.5;
sigma = 50*10^-6;
p[phi_] := (r*phi^3)/(24 sigma);
g[curlEprime_] := Exp[-((curlEprime)^2/2)];

gSomething[phi_, curlE_] := With[{p = p[phi]}, 
  p^(-(1/3)) (g[curlE - p] - g[curlE - 4 p]) + 
  NIntegrate[1/(curlE - curlEprime)^(1/3)  g'[curlEprime], 
    {curlEprime, curlE - p, curlE}]]

de[phi_, curlE_] := (2*e^2*n)/(3^(1/3)*
  Sqrt[2 Pi]*r^(2/3)*sigma^(4/3))*gSomething[phi, curlE]

phi = {.01, .02};
Quiet@Plot[de[#, curlE] & /@ phi, {curlE, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Evaluated -> True, PlotLegends -> ToString /@ phi]
```

[image]

Comment: I added the Plot and a comment about Capital letters, if you mind feel free to reverse the edit. Plus, if you are on V9 please add `PlotLegends -> ToString /@ phi` and update the image :)

Comment: Done, thank you!

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much. First of all, the code ran super fast (mine took about 5-10 minutes) and second of all the plots are beautiful (varied phi from 0.01 to 0.11)!